# How to edit a kali linux custom iso?

Tags: kali-linux, iso, livecd

I am creating a custom iso file of kali Following this guide: [Live Build a Custom Kali ISO](http://docs.kali.org/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso) . I added some packages to the chroot list, but forgot some others I need. After creating the iso is there some way to add packages without recreating all? The process is very long.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible if you live boot it since everything will be gone after a reboot.
You could install them each time you boot the iso if the tools don't require a reboot.
You could install that ISO somewhere so the changes remain after the reboot.
You could edit the build.sh scipt to not run `make clean` but that will probably break some other stuff since make clean is something you do before recompiling, to make sure you get a clean build and don't have left-over by-products from previous runs.